# Generate stock like data time series?

Tags: python, random, time-series, generator

Is there a quick way to generate random stock like data series ?

What I mean is data sequence which looks like a stock or a temperature or seasonal graph i.e. not jagged ups and downs, but more like a time based curve.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52628/generate-timeseries-data does this answer your question?

Comment: Don't pick random values, pick the random *difference* between successive values, with some time bias on the differences: mostly up for a bit, then mostly down.  Big differences for sharp movements; small differences for slow movements.  You will probably need to play with your program to get things right.

Comment: trying TimeSynth but not getting far ... and the only docs is the example on the github page ;(

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer I coded :

```
def gen(value, steps=10, trend=0, low=-10, high=10):
    new = value
    rv = []
    for i in range(steps) :
        new = trend + new + np.random.randint(low,high)
        rv.append(new)
    return rv   
        

plot(gen(100,steps=50))
```